# В контроллере перестала работать проверка параметров

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Неделю назад все работало, теперь нет никакой реакции на нажатие Up или Down (возможно какие-то обновления теперь мешают). 
Если в контроллере убрать if и оставить только `vote.score += 1` - действительно увеличивает.

```
#votes_controller.rb:
def update
  post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  vote = post.vote

  vote.score += 1 if params[:vote][:score] == 'Up'
  vote.score -= 1 if params[:vote][:score] == "Down"
  vote.users << current_user
  vote.save

  flash[:notice] = "You vote counted!"
  redirect_to post_path(post) 
end

#_update.html.erb 
<%= form_for [@post, @post.vote] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :score, "+"%>
  <%= f.radio_button :score, 'Up' %>
  <%= f.label :score, "-"%>
  <%= f.radio_button :score, "Down" %>  
  <%= f.text_field :score, :size => "2%x5", :readonly => true%>
  <%= f.submit "vote" %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

При голосовании Processing by VotesController#update в логах не появляется. (даже когда убрать If и голосование работает, в логах идут строчки, которые грузятся при открытии Post после Completed 200 OK): 
(ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/posts/css/bootstrap.css"):

actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in`call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
...)

Comment: А что в логах сервера при попытке проголосовать?

Comment: @Василиса, не нашла, как можно картинку вставить, поэтому скопировала текстом:

Comment: Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 13]]
  ↳ app/views/comments/_index.html.erb:2
  Rendered comments/_index.html.erb (Duration: 16.0ms | Allocations: 1865)
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (Duration: 10.1ms | Allocations: 4071)
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 60.4ms | Allocations: 12943)

Comment: /home/osboxes/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:119: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/osboxes/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:78: warning: The called method `find_asset' is defined here
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 5.1ms | Allocations: 567)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 159)

Comment: А и не надо картинку. И в комменты не надо. Отредактируйте пожалуйста вопрос и вставьте ту часть лога, которая появляется при нажатии на up/down. Начинаться будет с `Processing by VotesController#update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решила вместо radio_button использовать кнопки и @Василиса мне помогла реализовать.

В _update:

```
<%= f.submit :'Up', value: 'Up' %> 
<%= f.submit :'Down', value: 'Down' %>
```

В контроллере:

```
vote.score += 1 if params[:commit] == 'Up' 
vote.score -= 1 if params[:commit] == "Down"
```

Все заработало